# Is it possible to change where a nuget package adds files to a project?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

If I add a nuget package *Foo* it might add files to the Content folder in my project.

```
Content
|
- foo.js
- foo.min.js
- foo.map
```

What if I wanted something like:

```
Content
|
-    Foo
     |
     - foo.js
     - foo.min.js
     - foo.map
```

Most of the other questions I have found are talking about the location of the packages folder - is something like the above possible?

Answer (score 0):

NuGet does not put the files into a Content folder inside your project unless that is the folder you used. You can put the files in any subdirectory inside the project. The jQuery NuGet package puts its files in a Scripts subdirectory, for example, and it has the folder structure inside its NuGet package (.nupkg):

[image: jQuery NuGet package folder structure]

Note that the Content directory here is just tells NuGet that it should put the files in the project directory. It does not add the files into a Content directory but instead adds them inside a Scripts directory inside the project.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Nuget Package Manager puts all the .js files inside the 'Scripts' folder and .css files inside the 'Content' folder. But if you want to create a subfolder and categorize your packages, you will have to manually do that. Create a sub folder and move the files manually to it.

[image]